# Why is my solution for finding the maximum product of index difference and minimum index value of a pair working?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The question states - For an array, find the maximum value of (j-i)*min(a[j], a[i]), where i and j are distinct indices of the array in the range {0,1, .., n-1} where n is the array length.

I went with an ill-thought-out solution where I have 2 pointers at both ends of the array and reject the one with a smaller array value. But it is still working. How?

```
        i, j = 0, n-1
        ansSoFar = 0
        while i <= j:
            ansSoFar = max(ansSoFar, (j-i)*min(A[i], A[j]))
            if A[i] > A[j]:
                j -= 1
            else:
                i += 1
        return ansSoFar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose A[0] is the smaller out of A[0] and A[n-1].

In this case, this is the best pairing we could possibly get with A[0] because if we change the other half of the pair we will definitely reduce (j-i), and may also reduce the value of A[j].

So we know that the best answer is either the current value (including A[0] and A[n-1]), or the best we can get out of elements 1..n-1.

Similarly, if A[n-1] is the smaller, the best answer is either the current value or the best we can get out of elements 0..n-2.

The given code is therefore correct, because it evaluates the current value with the extremes, and then reduces the problem by chopping off the head or the tail as appropriate.